# how to get selected value from a option set crm 4 dynamics 2011 online

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, options-menu

This is a question related to using javascript with crm 4 2011 online

I created an optionset -status: open,closed and a onchange event handler that calls the function run with the context as parameter.

In js i tried the following and more:

```
function run(selectedItems)
{
    var s = selectedItems[0];
}
```

But i always get an undefined variable.

How can get the selected value from a optionset?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

i tried

```
function run() { 
alert("hello"); 
var texter = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_state_request").getSelectedOption().text; 
alert(texter); 
}
```

just now. Gettin this: 
Error in userdefined event of this field. 
field:new_state_request 
event:onchange 
error:undefined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

these are the right methods with an optionset attribute, for more information visit this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx

*get the text of selected option*

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fieldname").getText();
```

*get the numeric value of selected option*

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fieldname").getValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

try

**To Get the selected text of a OptionSet field**

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("CRMFieldName").getSelectedOption().text;
```

**To Get the selected value of a OptionSet field**

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("CRMFieldName").getSelectedOption().value;
```